# Диагностика работы Memcached и Prestashop

Tags: memcached, prestashop

- Произвел установку memcached и всех необходимых расширений для `php-cli` и, конечно, `php-apache2`.
- В административной панели включил использование `memcahed`, указал хост - 127.0.0.1.
- Проверил наличие открытого порта 11211 через `netstat -anp | grep tcp`. Слушает действительно только на 127.0.0.1
- Изменил в конфиге объем выделяемой памяти до 128mb и перезапустил `memcached` и заодно `apache`
- Открыв страницу интернет магазина (prestashop 1.5) проверил, что есть соединения на порт `11211`, их оказалось около 10 шт.

**Теперь самое интересное!**

При сравнении использования `с` и `без` `memcached` оказалось, что страница грузиться в среднем на **10** секунд **больше** в случае включения кэширования. Даже, если обновлять страницу (ту же что открыл) через `Ctrl+F5`, чтобы исключить кэш браузера.

**Вопросы**

1. Каков опыт использования `memcached` и `prestashop 1.5`, качественно ли работает эта связка?
2. Возможно ли такое поведение - временным, пока не накопятся объекты и данные из результатов запросов?
3. Если поведение не временное — почему ИМ так себя ведет при включении `memcached`?

**Информация**

- `memcached` установлен со стандартными настройками
- `PECL` расширение было установлено, как рекомендуют подсказки в ИМ
- Размер БД около 100 Мб
- БД - MySQL